# Choose of basis set

Tags: optimization, density-functional-theory

I am engaged with the syntheses and DFT calculations of coordination complexes. I wonder how can I set up the basis set for carried out using B3LYP method and mixed basis sets of LanL2DZ for Pd and 6-31+G(d) for all other atoms, in the use of DFT theory by Gaussian 09W. can any one please explain for me?

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is your need?

Comment: nicoguaro thank you very much for your correction, I need to now how I can set basis set for Pd(II) LANL2DZ and 6-31G for the other atoms in the Pd(II) complex I hope it is clear now, thank you again for your reply

Comment: Not really, but I'm not an expert in quantum chemistry. The problem is that your question as written right now is too specific and requires and expert to understand it.

Comment: You really should be reading the [Gaussian manual](http://www.gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/k_gen.htm) to answer this question. In general this is a very specific software usage question.